# error Command failed with exit code 1. in compile protobufjs

Tags: protobufjs

I update `protobufjs` from `6.11.2` to `7.1.2` then when I run my compiler to compile my protobufs I got this error

```
Usage: pbjs [options] <schema_path>

Options:
  -V, --version        output the version number
  --es5 <js_path>      Generate ES5 JavaScript code
  --es6 <js_path>      Generate ES6 JavaScript code
  --ts <ts_path>       Generate TypeScript code
  --decode <msg_type>  Decode standard input to JSON
  --encode <msg_type>  Encode standard input to JSON
  -h, --help           output usage information
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding `protobufjs-cli`.

```
yarn add protobufjs-cli
```